# Invalid Lambda Response: Lambda response provided invalid slot names [slotId]

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, bots, aws-lex

I get the error `Invalid Lambda Response: Lambda response provided invalid slot names [slotId]` when lambda sends response to lex using `elicitSlot` to get slot values for undefined slot.

I referred the lex blueprint code as following.

```
const handleOrder = async (intentRequest, callback) => {
    const source = intentRequest.invocationSource
    const id = intentRequest.currentIntent.slots.slotId

    if (source === 'DialogCodeHook') {
        // Perform basic validation on the supplied input slots.  Use the elicitSlot dialog action to re-prompt for the first violation detected.
        const slots = intentRequest.currentIntent.slots

        const validationResult = validateOrderRequest(id)
        if (!validationResult.isValid) {
            //reset the slot value
            slots[`${validationResult.violatedSlot}`] = null
            callback(elicitSlot(intentRequest.sessionAttributes, intentRequest.currentIntent.name, slots, validationResult.violatedSlot, validationResult.message))
            return;
        }
        const outputSessionAttributes = intentRequest.sessionAttributes || {}
        callback(delegate(outputSessionAttributes, intentRequest.currentIntent.slots))
        return;
    }

    ...
}

function validateOrderRequest(id) {
    if(!id){
        return buildValidationResult(false, 'slotId', `Tell me the ID.`);
    }
}
```

**What could be giving the error?**

Answer (score -1):

You need not to use the statement

slots[`${validationResult.violatedSlot}`] = null;

It's not good practice to assign a slot value to null.

Remove this statement. I hope you won't get that error.